# Vscode extension updated and deleted old extension folder

Tags: visual-studio-code

In a move of swift ignorance, I modified an vscode extension configuration file and placed it in the following path" `C:\Users\{user}\.vscode\extensions\{extensionId}-1.4.0`. The other night, I updated the extension to version 1.5.0. Upon restarting vscode, something was off, and I discovered that the path mentioned previously was removed and replaced with the exact same path, except this path now ended with `${extensionId}-1.5.0`. The configuration file I had stored in the 1.4.0 folder was not copied over to the 1.5.0 folder, and I haven't been able to locate it in any vscode "settings backups" or my recycle bin. Is the old extension folder still on my disk anywhere? If it is, where can I look?

Needless to say, I will not be storing any files I care about in vscode extension folders in the future.

Comment: what configuration file did you change

Comment: css configuration of a theme

Answer (score 0):

Is the old extension folder still on my disk anywhere?

No. It has been deleted via Windows API, not through Windows recycle bin, so no way to recover. You can use some professional tools, but they won't guarantee either.

You simply described how VS Code works internally when updating extensions, so everything is well known and by design. Thus, you are not supposed to make any local changes in extension folders (and you  should not assume extensions are to be expanded in such folders as well).

Extension authors should have known such for a long while and understood how to live with this mechanism.